# Python - How do I convert "an OS-level handle to an open file" to a file object?

Tags: python, temporary-files, mkstemp, fdopen

[tempfile.mkstemp()](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-tempfile.html) returns:

> a tuple containing an OS-level handle to an open file (as would be returned by os.open()) and the absolute pathname of that file, in that order.

How do I convert that OS-level handle to a file object?

The [documentation for os.open()](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/os-fd-ops.html) states:

> To wrap a file descriptor in a "file
>   object", use fdopen().

So I tried:

```
>>> import tempfile
>>> tup = tempfile.mkstemp()
>>> import os
>>> f = os.fdopen(tup[0])
>>> f.write('foo\n')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Comment: Remember to mark an answer as "Accepted" if it worked for you.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use

```
os.write(tup[0], "foo\n")
```

to write to the handle.

If you want to open the handle for writing you need to add the **"w"** mode

```
f = os.fdopen(tup[0], "w")
f.write("foo")
```

Comment: That works--thanks.  But technically fdopen returns a file object (and you pass in a file descriptor), so if I could edit your answer I'd change it to "f = os.fdopen(tup[0], "w");f.write("foo")

Comment: If you don't use `os.fdopen`, you need to make sure you close the temp file handle with os.close(tup[0]) according to http://www.logilab.org/blogentry/17873.

Answer (score 13):

Here's how to do it using a with statement:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from contextlib import closing
fd, filepath = tempfile.mkstemp()
with closing(os.fdopen(fd, 'w')) as tf:
    tf.write('foo\n')
```

Comment: Is `closing` really necessary? `os.fdopen` returns a `TextIOWrapper` whose `__exit__` turned out to close it, tested on Python 3.5 (CPython).

Answer (score 6):

You forgot to specify the open mode ('w') in fdopen(). The default is 'r', causing the write() call to fail.

I think mkstemp() creates the file for reading only. Calling fdopen with 'w' probably reopens it for writing (you *can* reopen the file created by mkstemp).

Comment: a temporary (hence empty) file ready only for reading would be useless. mkstemp returns the file opened in binary mode for both reading and writing, per the docstring.

Answer (score 4):

```
temp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
temp.file.write('foo\n')
temp.close()
```

Comment: The "delete" parameter was added in version 2.6, so that won't work for older Python versions.

Answer (score 2):

What's your goal, here?  Is `tempfile.TemporaryFile` inappropriate for your purposes?

Comment: I don't want the file destroyed as soon as it's closed.  (And I want to be sure the file to be visible.)

Comment: then you can pass delete=False to NamedTemporaryFile

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on the answers, so I will post my comment here:

To create a temporary file for write access you can use tempfile.mkstemp and specify "w" as the last parameter, like:

```
f = tempfile.mkstemp("", "", "", "w") # first three params are 'suffix, 'prefix', 'dir'...
os.write(f[0], "write something")
```