# Too many open files when run an external script with multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```py
def func(item, protein, ncpu):

    output = None

    item_id = item.id

    output_fname = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='_output.json', text=True)[1]
    input_fname = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='_input.pdbqt', text=True)[1]   # <-- error occurs here

    try:
        with open(input_fname, 'wt') as f:
            f.write(preprocess(item))   # <- convert item to text format, not important

        python_exec = sys.executable
        cmd = f'{python_exec} script.py -i {input_fname} -p {protein} -o {output_fname} -c {ncpu}'
        subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)

        with open(output_fname) as f:
            res = f.read()
            if res:
                res = json.loads(res)
                output = {'score': res['score'],
                          'block': res['poses']}

    finally:
        os.unlink(input_fname)
        os.unlink(output_fname)

    return item_id, output


with Pool(ncpu) as pool:
    for item_id, res in pool.imap_unordered(partial(func, **kwargs), tuple(items), chunksize=1):
        yield item_id, res
```

I process multiple items using `multiprocessing.Pool`. For every item I run a python script from `subprocess` shell. Before, I created two temporary files and pass them as arguments to the script. The `script.py` calls C-extension which process an item. After, I parse the output json file and return values, if any. Temporary files should be destroyed. in a `finally` section. However, after I process 3880-3920 items I got an error:

```
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavlop/anaconda3/envs/vina_cache/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 125, in worker
  File "/home/pavlop/python/docking-scripts/moldock/vina_dock.py", line 93, in func
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/var/tmp/pbs.147815.login/tmpp8tqblfv_input.pdbqt'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pavlop/python/docking-scripts/moldock/run_dock.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/pavlop/python/docking-scripts/moldock/run_dock.py", line 203, in main
    for i, (item_id, res) in enumerate(docking(mols,
  File "/home/pavlop/python/docking-scripts/moldock/run_dock.py", line 74, in docking
    for item_id, res in pool.imap_unordered(partial(func, **kwargs), tuple(items), chunksize=1):
  File "/home/pavlop/anaconda3/envs/vina_cache/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 870, in next
    raise value
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/var/tmp/pbs.147815.login/tmpp8tqblfv_input.pdbqt'
```

What do I do wrong or miss? Why file descriptors are not released? Could it happen that C-extension does not release file descriptors?

I see that temporary files are created and removed as expected. `ulimit` (soft and hard) was set to 1000000. I checked all my code and all files are opened using `with` statement to avoid leaking.

If I replace `multiprocessing.Pool` with `dask` cluster, everything works as expected, no errors.

UPDATE:

I checked output of `lsof`. Really both temporary files remain open for every item and they are accumulated over time in every running process, but they have status? (deleted). So the issue in that how I manage them. However, since the `ulimit` is large, I should not observe this error.

UPDATE2:

It seems that I have to close descriptors manually. It worked on a test run, have to check on a larger run.

```py
fd, name - tempfile.mkstemp()
try:
    ...
finally:
    os.close(fd)
    os.unlink(name)
```

Comment: You could comment out the subprocess call (and adjust the remaining code accordingly) to check if the subprocess causes the problem.

Comment: Good idea! Unfortunately the error persists, occurred after 3700 processed items.

Comment: @MichaelButscher, the problem should be in management of temporary files, see update

Comment: `mkstemp` creates a file and also returns a file descriptor to the open file (which isn't closed and accumulates). You can wrap the file descriptor in a file object (instead of creating new file objects) as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296063/987358

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was indeed as proposed in the UPDATE2. A file descriptor should be explicitly closed. It is not enough just to remove a file.

```py
fd, name - tempfile.mkstemp()
try:
    ...
finally:
    os.close(fd)
    os.unlink(name)
```